# Render svg twig - Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, svg, twig

This is a working svg.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
<g id="home">
  <path fill="#90A4AE" d="M42,48H6c-3.3,0-6-2.7-6-6V6c0-3.3,2.7-6,6-6h36c3.3,0,6,2.7,6,6v36C48,45.3,45.3,48,42,48z"/>
  <path fill="#212121" d="M20.8,35.5v-9.6h6.4v9.6h8V22.7H40L24,8.3L8,22.7h4.8v12.8H20.8z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

When I try to load it dynamicly with twig I don't have anything rendered

This is what I'm doing

```
<svg style="display:none;">
    <defs>
        {% for item in items %}
            <g id="{{item.label}}">
                {{item.svg}}
            </g>
        {% endfor %}
</svg>
```

Later

```
    {% for item in items %}
        <li class="nav__items ">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
                <use xlink:href=#{{item.label}}></use>
            </svg>
            <a href="{{item.target}}">{{item.label}}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

When I inspect the resulted html, the use is working. I can find the home content svg inside. But nothing is printed. Of course, if I use it directly without twig it works :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [raw](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html) filter to tell Twig to not escape the content of your item:

```
<svg style="display:none;">
    <defs>
        {% for item in items %}
            <g id="{{item.label}}">
                {{item.svg|raw}}
            </g>
        {% endfor %}
</svg>
```

You might also want to remove `style="display:none;"`